# ImageView disappearing with FlingAnimation

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to get an image to move across the screen using the fling animation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/fling-animation). The activity is using a constraint layout and only two views are on it - the button and the imageview. When the ball starts to move up the y-axis, it eventually disappears.   Here is a GIF that shows the problem https://gyazo.com/cc822247117485beb8d0aa8316072b00

Code for moving ball:

```
//Button code
public void start(View v) {

    FlingAnimation fling = new FlingAnimation(ball, DynamicAnimation.SCROLL_Y);
    fling.setMinValue(0)
            .setFriction(1.1f)
            .setStartVelocity(1000);


    fling.addUpdateListener(new DynamicAnimation.OnAnimationUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(DynamicAnimation animation, float value, float velocity) {
            ball.setX(ball.getX() + 4);
        }
    });

    fling.addEndListener(new DynamicAnimation.OnAnimationEndListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(DynamicAnimation animation, boolean canceled, float value, float velocity) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    });

    fling.start();


}
```

Comment: How about [setting a max value](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/animation/FlingAnimation#setmaxvalue) to the FlingAnimation?

Comment: That did not seem to help :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing indeed, but the reason is that `DynamicAnimation.SCROLL_Y` is just scrolling your view in the bounds of it position, so it just disappearing in the end. You can see this if you will write something like:

```
fling.addEndListener(new DynamicAnimation.OnAnimationEndListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(DynamicAnimation animation, boolean canceled, float value, float velocity) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
        v.setScrollY(0);
    }
});
```

You will see the view pop back to it original position.

The solution is quite simple: Don't use `DynamicAnimation.SCROLL_Y`, instead use: `DynamicAnimation.Y`.